# How to call an a 2D Array (Matrix) In a Soap WebService

Tags: java, android, arrays, web-services, soap

I am stuck in calling an Array of Type  double[][] in a Soap Webservice. Actually, I have configured my Soap Webservice at my glass fish and it is generating randomly two Arrays (Matrices), then multiply both the matrices and return the resulted matrix (2D Array). I am stuck in how to call the Array from Client. I can call any string or int value but dunt know how to call an array. The Webservice sucessfully generate the Matrices and then Multiply both. I have tested it in  http://172.25.181.23:8080/TestWebService/ResourceClassService?Tester

here is the browser test result:

```
matrixMulti Method invocation


Method parameter(s)

Type    Value
int 
10
int 
10
Method returned

java.util.List : "[org.moeez.javabrains.ModelClass@96c762]"
SOAP Request

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:MatrixMulti xmlns:ns2="http://javabrains.moeez.org/">
            <arg0>10</arg0>
            <arg1>10</arg1>
        </ns2:MatrixMulti>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
SOAP Response

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:MatrixMultiResponse xmlns:ns2="http://javabrains.moeez.org/">
            <return>
                <result>
                    <item>16675.0</item>
                    <item>23888.0</item>
                    <item>31099.0</item>
                    <item>18575.0</item>
                    <item>17015.0</item>
                    <item>30272.0</item>
                    <item>26010.0</item>
                    <item>21229.0</item>
                    <item>14888.0</item>
                    <item>24212.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>25347.0</item>
                    <item>28895.0</item>
                    <item>39055.0</item>
                    <item>20141.0</item>
                    <item>24993.0</item>
                    <item>34906.0</item>
                    <item>30242.0</item>
                    <item>30895.0</item>
                    <item>20351.0</item>
                    <item>26011.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>12012.0</item>
                    <item>24454.0</item>
                    <item>28071.0</item>
                    <item>14582.0</item>
                    <item>18386.0</item>
                    <item>23981.0</item>
                    <item>21852.0</item>
                    <item>22986.0</item>
                    <item>13975.0</item>
                    <item>21444.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>15691.0</item>
                    <item>28936.0</item>
                    <item>29329.0</item>
                    <item>16119.0</item>
                    <item>20362.0</item>
                    <item>30584.0</item>
                    <item>29399.0</item>
                    <item>27267.0</item>
                    <item>20573.0</item>
                    <item>29378.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>15118.0</item>
                    <item>27503.0</item>
                    <item>29980.0</item>
                    <item>11625.0</item>
                    <item>20176.0</item>
                    <item>31631.0</item>
                    <item>24869.0</item>
                    <item>24998.0</item>
                    <item>15587.0</item>
                    <item>33234.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>24949.0</item>
                    <item>34045.0</item>
                    <item>40347.0</item>
                    <item>20842.0</item>
                    <item>27634.0</item>
                    <item>40127.0</item>
                    <item>38795.0</item>
                    <item>34945.0</item>
                    <item>24957.0</item>
                    <item>33485.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>15731.0</item>
                    <item>21584.0</item>
                    <item>27399.0</item>
                    <item>19865.0</item>
                    <item>13156.0</item>
                    <item>28831.0</item>
                    <item>24961.0</item>
                    <item>15857.0</item>
                    <item>21462.0</item>
                    <item>21472.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>25052.0</item>
                    <item>29964.0</item>
                    <item>34718.0</item>
                    <item>19675.0</item>
                    <item>24144.0</item>
                    <item>35858.0</item>
                    <item>31764.0</item>
                    <item>32143.0</item>
                    <item>19417.0</item>
                    <item>32549.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>15470.0</item>
                    <item>26586.0</item>
                    <item>24474.0</item>
                    <item>15548.0</item>
                    <item>17297.0</item>
                    <item>29695.0</item>
                    <item>26752.0</item>
                    <item>26596.0</item>
                    <item>18556.0</item>
                    <item>22777.0</item>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <item>14608.0</item>
                    <item>28779.0</item>
                    <item>30670.0</item>
                    <item>10239.0</item>
                    <item>18995.0</item>
                    <item>30324.0</item>
                    <item>26900.0</item>
                    <item>26970.0</item>
                    <item>18125.0</item>
                    <item>34044.0</item>
                </result>
            </return>
        </ns2:MatrixMultiResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

When I am testing it from android device, it is giving an error as below:

```
ava.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be 
cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive
07-31 17:53:37.983  12082-12140/com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap 
W/System.err﹕ at  
com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground
```

(MainActivity.java:115)

```
07-31 17:53:37.983  12082-12140/com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap  
W/System.err﹕ at 
com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground
(MainActivity.java:80)
07-31 17:53:37.983  12082-12140/com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap 
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-31 17:53:37.983  12082-12140/com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap 
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-31 17:53:37.983  12082-12140/com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap 
W/System.err﹕ at 
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-31 17:53:37.983  12082-12140/com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap 
W/System.err﹕ at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-31 17:53:37.983  12082-12140/com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap 
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-31 17:53:37.983  12082-12140/com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap 
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am going to attach my Client Codes here.

package com.example.mushtaqali.offloadwithsoap;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://javabrains.moeez.org/MatrixMulti";
    private static String NAME_SPACE = "http://javabrains.moeez.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "MatrixMulti";
    private static String URL = "http://172.25.181.23:8080/TestWebService/ResourceClassService";

    Button enter, clr;
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
    EditText et1, et2;
    private String re;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        clr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                MyTask mytask = new MyTask(et1.getText().toString(), et2.getText().toString());
                mytask.execute();


            }
        });

        clr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {

            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et1.setText("");
                et2.setText("");
                tv1.setText("");
                et1.requestFocus();
            }

        });

    }


    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapPrimitive> {

        private final String a;
        private final String b;

        MyTask(String a, String b) {

            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected SoapPrimitive doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
            request.addProperty("arg0", a);
            request.addProperty("arg1", b);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            SoapPrimitive resultString = null;

            try {
                aht.call(SOAP_ACTION1, soapEnvelope);
                resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultString;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SoapPrimitive resultString) {
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(resultString!=null)
            tv1.setText(resultString.toString());


        }


    }
}
```

Please suggest how to call this array/ what to add in my codes to call it. Thanks

Comment: The problem is this line in your `doInBackground` method: `resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();`. You are receiving a `SoapObject` but trying to cast it to a SoapPrimitive. I imagine you'll need to receive it like `SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();` and then work with the `SoapObject`, but I don't really know about Android programming.

Comment: I have used the same logic in many apps, like sending two int numbers to webservice and add the numbers and get the result back. The same logic worked there perfectly. Here, It is giving an error. I am confuse if thats the issue then why it worked there ? :/

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the web service you're calling. The logic is fine, you just need to deal with an Object not a Primitive. You're even passing an object in your request. I'm not sure of the API here, but changing your code to deal with an object rather than a primitive is clearly what's needed.